# how to send data at any moment ( simultaneous ) in windows?

Tags: c, asynchronous, winapi, ipc, named-pipes

I want write a namedpipe client in windows OS, which can send data at any time even the client is receiving data.[Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/desktop/ipc/named-pipe-client) of MSDN only shows that sending data after receive something.And the serial operation is not what I want. Because the data I transfer between client and server is not so big,that is to say, IO operation should not be a time-consuming process, I didn't use `OVERLAP` in client.

The code that I modify in MSDN example of client is as below:
the main thread keep reading data, and the child-thread keep sending data to server. However, the server blocked when reading data when debugging.

```
std::thread t([&] {
    cbToWrite = (lstrlen(lpvMessage) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Sending %d byte message: \"%s\"\n"), cbToWrite, lpvMessage);


    fSuccess = WriteFile(
        hPipe,                  // pipe handle
        lpvMessage,             // message
        cbToWrite,              // message length
        &cbWritten,             // bytes written
        NULL);                  // not overlapped

    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("WriteFile to pipe failed. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nMessage sent to server, receiving reply as follows:\n");

});

while (1)   // main thread always reading
{
    do
    {
        // Read from the pipe.

        fSuccess = ReadFile(
            hPipe,    // pipe handle
            chBuf,    // buffer to receive reply
            BUFSIZE * sizeof(TCHAR),  // size of buffer
            &cbRead,  // number of bytes read
            NULL);    // not overlapped

        if (!fSuccess && GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            break;

        _tprintf(TEXT("\"%s\"\n"), chBuf);
    } while (!fSuccess);  // repeat loop if ERROR_MORE_DATA

    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("ReadFile from pipe failed. GLE=%d\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
}


t.join();
```

I expect someone can correct that code to get it work, or can you tell the standard practice or suggestions? 
Thanks so much!

Comment: Why a pipe and not a socket?

Comment: you want asynchronous I/O functional. so and create files with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and use asynchronous io. in this case you can send/receiver data in paralell

Comment: if you create file in not asyncronous mode all I/O operations is secuential - the new I/O is not begin until old not complete. so write operation will begin until read complete.

Comment: "*I want write a namedpipe client in windows OS, which can send data at any time even the client is receiving data*" - a pipe is not a good choice for that. Data typically flows in only one direction at a time, and you can easily deadlock your code if you try to send data in both directions in parallel. A socket would make a better choice, as it is truly directional.

Comment: *and you can easily deadlock your code if you try to send data in both directions in parallel* - with asynchronous duplex pipe we can send in both directions and never deadlock

Comment: my current scheme is creating two threads to write and read separately, each of which has a overlap object. Do you think it will be OK?

Comment: @Gordon - no, this of course will be not ok, even if you create 1000 threads. only asynchronous io files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) documentation about **`FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`**

> If this flag is specified, the file can be used for **simultaneous**
>   read and write operations.
>
> If this flag is not specified, then I/O operations are **serialized**

I/O operations are serialized mean that the new I/O request will be wait until previous not complete. so even use multiple threads here not help, if you not use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`. for example you can from one thread begin read operation and wait until data not exist. if you call write on this file from another thread - write will be wait in I/O subsystem code, until your read not complete. even if you say query file name (via `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` with `FileNameInfo`) this request will be serialized and wait until your read not completed.

so only option for simultaneous I/O operations (not only read write but all) use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` when you create file.